# Show popup with info brought from a table element in react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, api

I'm developing an app in React.JS and I have to display information that further details the selected element of a table.

I share an image as an explanation so that it can be understood or what I need to do.

[image]

How can I do it? I understand that you have to pass variables to the popup so that they are taken and displayed according to the selected element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use case, create a local state in the component and update the details on click of the selected record and pass the state to the modal.

Here I created a `selectedData` state for populating the selected records and updating this state when onClick of `more details`in the table and also passing them as props to the modal so that it shows up in the UI.

Complete Code:-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1001,
    firstname: "Mark",
    lastname: "Otto",
    age: 34,
    location: "London",
    address: "10 Downing Street"
  },
  {
    id: 1002,
    firstname: "Jacob",
    lastname: "Jacob",
    age: 34,
    location: "India",
    address: "#110 broad Street"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState({});
  const hanldeClick = (selectedRec) => {
    setSelectedData(selectedRec);
    setShow(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setShow(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Location</th>
            <th scope="col">Show More</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((v) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{v.id}</td>
              <td>{v.firstname}</td>
              <td>{v.lastname}</td>
              <td>@{v.location}</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#" onClick={() => hanldeClick(v)}>
                  More details
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {show && <Modal details={selectedData} handleClose={hideModal} />}
    </div>
  );
}

const Modal = ({ handleClose, details }) => {

  return (
    <div className="modal display-block">
      <section className="modal-main">
        <div className="App">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Age</th>
                <th scope="col">Location</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{details?.id}</td>
                <td>{details?.firstname}</td>
                <td>{details?.lastname}</td>
                <td>{details?.age}</td>
                <td>{details?.location}</td>
                <td>{details?.address}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClose}>close</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Working Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lamarr-hy8hu?file=/src/App.js:0-2625

Hope you are looking for the same use case. Let me know if you are facing any issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I will review it. I'll tell you later.

Comment: It works perfectly, and it is very useful to me. Thank!!

Comment: I have posted one more detail that I would need to understand to keep learning and developing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390482/show-a-pop-up-window-with-information-coming-from-an-element-and-its-totals-fro. You can help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: Ok sure I will go through it.

Comment: I have answered your question. Please go through and validate.