# Show a pop-up window with information coming from an element and its totals, from one of the table in react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, popup

I'm developing an application in React.Js.

I have the array:

```
array = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "202001"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "price": 100
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "price": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "I2"
    },
    "price": 300
  },
]
```

And I show the data as shown in the table:

| ITEM | 202001 | 202002 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| I2 | - | 300 | 300 |
| TOTAL | 100 | 500 | 600 |

And I did this to get those values:

```
items_dicc = array.reduce((acc, e) => {
    if (!acc[e["item"]["name"]]) {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]] = {
        [e["date"]["name"]]: e["price"]
      }
    } else {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]][e["date"]["name"]] = e["price"]
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

dates = [...new Set(Object.keys(items_dicc).map(i => Object.keys(items_dicc[i])).flat())]

totalSumPerDate = {};

dates.forEach(date => {
  const sumOnDate = Object.values(items_dicc).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc = acc + (curr[date]? curr[date] : 0);
    return acc;
  }, 0);
  totalSumPerDate[[date]] = sumOnDate;
});

totalSum = Object.values(totalSumPerDate).reduce((acc, curr) => acc+curr, 0);

sumPerItem = {};

Object.keys(items_dicc).forEach(key => {
   const sum = Object.values(items_dicc[key]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
   sumPerItem[[key]] = sum;
});


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      {dates.map(date => <th>{date}</th>)}
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {
    Object.keys(items_dicc).map((item) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{item}</td>
          {dates.map((date) => <td>{items_dicc[item][date] || ''}</td>)}
          <td>{sumPerItem[item]}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL</td>
        {Object.values(totalSumPerDate).map(item => <td>{item}</td>)}
      <td>{totalSum}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to be able to show through a popup other data that the array may contain (for example the id).

[image: popup]

I understand that to do this it is necessary to create a local state in the component to update the details when clicking on the selected record and pass the state to the modal.

It should also be able to bring in the totals info.

How can I do it, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach,

You have to create a local state for the selected record of the table row and pass it to the modal component. Update the selected record on click of the table row.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date: {
      id: 1,
      name: "202001"
    },
    item: {
      id: 1,
      name: "I1"
    },
    price: 100
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: {
      id: 2,
      name: "202002"
    },
    item: {
      id: 1,
      name: "I1"
    },
    price: 200
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date: {
      id: 2,
      name: "202002"
    },
    item: {
      id: 2,
      name: "I2"
    },
    price: 300
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState({});
  const hanldeClick = (selectedId) => {
    const selectedRec = array.find((val) => val.item.name === selectedId);
    setSelectedData(selectedRec);
    setShow(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setShow(false);
  };
  const items_dicc = array.reduce((acc, e) => {
    if (!acc[e["item"]["name"]]) {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]] = {
        [e["date"]["name"]]: e["price"]
      };
    } else {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]][e["date"]["name"]] = e["price"];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const dates = [
    ...new Set(
      Object.keys(items_dicc)
        .map((i) => Object.keys(items_dicc[i]))
        .flat()
    )
  ];

  const totalSumPerDate = {};

  dates.forEach((date) => {
    const sumOnDate = Object.values(items_dicc).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc = acc + (curr[date] ? curr[date] : 0);
      return acc;
    }, 0);
    totalSumPerDate[[date]] = sumOnDate;
  });

  const totalSum = Object.values(totalSumPerDate).reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc + curr,
    0
  );

  const sumPerItem = {};

  Object.keys(items_dicc).forEach((key) => {
    const sum = Object.values(items_dicc[key]).reduce(
      (acc, curr) => acc + curr,
      0
    );
    sumPerItem[[key]] = sum;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ITEM</th>
            {dates.map((date) => (
              <th>{date}</th>
            ))}
            <th>TOTAL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(items_dicc).map((item) => {
            return (
              <tr onClick={() => hanldeClick(item)}>
                <td>{item}</td>
                {dates.map((date) => (
                  <td>{items_dicc[item][date] || ""}</td>
                ))}
                <td>{sumPerItem[item]}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
          <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td>
            {Object.values(totalSumPerDate).map((item) => (
              <td>{item}</td>
            ))}
            <td>{totalSum}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {show && <Modal details={selectedData} handleClose={hideModal} />}
    </>
  );
}

const Modal = ({ handleClose, details }) => {
  console.log(details);
  return (
    <div className="modal display-block">
      <section className="modal-main">
        <div className="App">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ITEM</th>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">DATE</th>
                <th scope="col">PRICE</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{details?.item?.name}</td>
                <td>{details?.item?.id}</td>
                <td>{details?.date?.name}</td>
                <td>{details?.price}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClose}>close</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-moore-rsn97?file=/src/App.js:0-3665

Comment: Thanks a lot! Some adjustments are needed, but that's the way. I'll tell you later.

Comment: Hello @Sarun UK. For whatever reason it returns the same result if I select a period for the same item. And in total the detail of the last period is shown. The idea is that it shows the item detail for each period and in total it shows the detail of the entire row or the entire column, depending on which one is selected. How do we solve it? Another thing to solve is to do the same for the totals for each period.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the total data to the onClickEventHandler like this,

```
    <tr onClick={(event) => yourHandler(event, item, sumPerItem[item])}>
      <td>{item}</td>
      {dates.map((date) => <td>{items_dicc[item][date] || ''}</td>)}
      <td>{sumPerItem[item]}</td>
    </tr>
```

The event handler should be written like this,

```
yourHandler = (event, currentItem, totalForRow) => {
    // You update the state here 
}
```

This method is for whole row. If you want to show different data on each cell click you need to add the eventHandler on  elements and update the method parameters according to your need.

Comment: I'll try to implement it, I'll tell you later. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello @sabbir.alam! Could you detail a little more the way you solve it? Thank you!